# timthumb.php and htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

My PHP site (not Wordpress) is using timthumb.php and I get img related errors because it can't access `/team/assets/images/upload-img.jpg?h=50&w=50`, but it works without query parameters:
`/team/assets/images/upload-img.jpg`.

Which rewrite rules should I add in order to support those query parameters for image resizing? At the moment I only have a default htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Here is a full (bad request) url: `https://example.com/team/includes/timthumb.php?src=https://example.com/team/assets/images/upload-img.jpg?h=50&w=50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not a .htaccess problem. You’re using `$` instead of `&`. The URL should be:

```
https://example.com/team/includes/timthumb.php?src=https://example.com/team/assets/images/upload-img.jpg&h=50&w=50
```

Comment: good catch, however I still get `A TimThumb error has occured`, which doesn't happen on localhost, only on prod server...

Comment: @StewieGriffin The error should include more information than that. If it’s a different problem, I suggest to ask a new question that includes the other information about the error.